# Debugging Exception on Custom Error Page

Tags: asp.net

I'm seeing this error on my server:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

I know how to fix the first exception (EF migration issue in application initialization), but I don't like the fact that it won't load my custom error page (static html page). Is it possible to load a custom error page when the application won't initialize? If so, how do I go about debugging what the issue was with the custom error page?

Comment: This is a common problem when your error page causes an error. You should make sure as much as possible that you error page doesn't have any code that might throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @mason. I've clarified that my error page is a static html page.

Comment: Do you have any HTTP modules in your application that might be  causing the error?